# Rescued blind cat

Tags: cats

We’ve rescued a birth blind kitten, that has been abused by his owner (he was hitting him hard). Now the cat is save with us at home, but he is very scared, keep hissing and being aggressive even when no one around. I understand that cat is so much traumatized, but may be someone can advise what we cat do to help him.
It’s obviously that he can’t see, and every move or new smell will freak him out. Should we keep him closed for some time without any interuction or we should introduce ourselves and come to room from time to time?

Comment: to make the kitten more comfortable at the moment give him/her a t shirt that you have used and put this where the kitten sleep/rest.do you know how old the kitten might be? wellcome to pets.

Answer (score 3):

It takes time to build trust. Letting him express his anxiety without further stress (approaching him when unwanted) or repercussions (maybe he was struck when hissing?) will let him learn he's safe in spite of his fears. If you stay away from him, it will take longer for him to learn this.

Talk to him, a lot, so he knows when there are humans around. He may react by being stressed/aggressive, but he will learn that when there's no voice, he's safe from humans. He will also learn that there's no harm even when there are humans around.

Even if it's not appreciated yet, periodically give him high-value treats when you're talking, or upon walking into his room: a small bit of chicken, a bit of cream, etc., to let him know that your voice = something good.

Because he's blind, use sound to let him know when something is going to happen. (I warn my dogs - who are sighted - when a loud noise is about to start. Before starting the vacuum cleaner or blender, etc., I will say, "Loud noise now!" Once I have their attention, I'll repeat it. This helps them to stay calm.) Think of all the sudden noises that might scare him, and let him learn to expect them. (e.g. "TV going to get turned on!", "I'm going to vacuum now!") Also, always tell him when you're going to approach him. ("I'm coming over now" or other specific. With a small treat, of course; it could be food, or it could be sensory. My orphaned kittens liked a towel-wrapped bottle of warm water.)

The most important things are patience and time. You might ask your Vet if there is a cat-appeasing pheromone (like Feliway Friends) that can help soothe him when you're around.

Comment: Nice answer, I'd add that refraining from moving things around does help a lot getting blind cats to relax. They will memorize the layout of the house and use pheromone markings to navigate the place, and major changes can promote insecurity.